# How can I test using linearHypothesis equation "BI+BI:factor(Year==2018)TRUE=0" wihtout an error?

Tags: r, plm

I have to test "BI+BI:factor(Year==2018)TRUE=0" using linearHypothesis in R, but I receive an error stating *The hypothesis "BI+(BI:factor(Year==2018)TRUE= 0" is not well formed: contains more than one = sign.*
I tried this:

```
linearHypothesis(fixed, "BI+(BI:factor(Year==2018)TRUE= 0")
```

Can you please help me with this issue? (I am new to R)

The model looks like this:

```
fixed <- plm(formula = NP ~ factor(N) + Industry + Size + BI + BI*(factor(Year==2012)+factor(Year==2013)+factor(Year==2014) +factor(Year==2015)+factor(Year==2016)+factor(Year==2017)+factor(Year==2018)+factor(Year==2019)) + OC + ATP + IntP + Ceff, data = pbi, na.action = na.omit, model="within", effect = "twoways")
```

I have a panel data with 416 companies over 9 years (3744 observations, I have NAs in data). I've indexed companies and years before. NP is net profit, BI - is whether company has BI product or not. Trying to see the changing effect of BI.

[I've got results that in 2018 and 2019 the BI*years variable is significant, but my model has a negative adjusted R squared. I should test it so these will be the coefficients for 2018 and 2019 - the difference between companies with BI and without BI in 2018 and 2019. Test that these amounts are zero. If I reject, it will mean that in 2018 and 2019 this effect is already significant.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoTv7.png)

I'm new to statistics and having a hard time with this panel data:(

Comment: can you show the code used to make the model and the coefficients

Comment: and what are you trying to test? Both BI and one of the interaction terms to be zero?

Comment: can you edit your post and put this information in? very hard to read off comments

Comment: Problem solved by dividing variable **Years** into separate years (I also had to change it the model) to avoid multiple = in linearHypothesis function.